# 'exclude' argument is not working with get_posts for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, exclude

I'm trying to use get_posts to get a random list of customPostTypes but I want to exclude some id's.

I already try the query with the following options:

```
Current) 'exclude'  => array(622, 621)
---    
a) 'post__not_in' => array(622, 621)
---
b) 'post__not_in' => array('622', '621')
---
c) 'exclude' => array('622', '621')
---
d) 'post__not_in' => '622, 621'
---
e) 'exclude' => '622, 621'
```

none of these options seems to work. Here is the full Query:

```
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'orderby'     => 'rand',
        'exclude'     => array(622, 621),
        'post_type'   => 'video',
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    print_r($posts);
```

Output:

```
==>>>>  Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 662 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2015-10-14 18:41:55 [post_date_gmt] => 2015-10-14 18:41:55 [post_content] => [post_title] => wow [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => wow [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2015-10-14 18:41:55 [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-10-14 18:41:55 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] => http://example.com//?post_type=video&p=662 [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => video [post_mime_type] => [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) )
```

Post type definition:

```
// UI labels
$labels = array(
  'name'                => _x( 'Videos', 'Post Type General Name', 'combustion' ),
  'singular_name'       => _x( 'Video', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'combustion' ),
  'menu_name'           => __( 'Videos', 'combustion' ),
  'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Video', 'combustion' ),
  'all_items'           => __( 'All Videos', 'combustion' ),
  'view_item'           => __( 'View Video', 'combustion' ),
  'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Video', 'combustion' ),
  'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'combustion' ),
  'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Video', 'combustion' ),
  'update_item'         => __( 'Update Video', 'combustion' ),
  'search_items'        => __( 'Search Video', 'combustion' ),
  'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'combustion' ),
  'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'combustion' )
);

// Other options

$post_args = array(
  'label'               => __( 'video', 'combustion' ),
  'menu_icon'           => __( 'dashicons-format-video' ),
  'description'         => __( 'Videos', 'combustion' ),
  'labels'              => $labels,
  // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
  'supports'            => array( 'title' ),
  'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' ),
  'hierarchical'        => false,
  'public'              => true,
  'show_ui'             => true,
  'show_in_menu'        => false,
  'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
  'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
  'menu_position'       => 5,
  'can_export'          => true,
  'has_archive'         => true,
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'publicly_queryable'  => true,
  'capability_type'     => 'post'
);

// Registering Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'video', $post_args );
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or missing something!

Comment: Your output is showing a post with ID 662, but you're excluding 621 and 622. What are you demonstrating with the output?